# Знаки битовых полей

Tags: c

Имеют ли значения знаки битовых полей? Нужно ли как-то учитывать знаки полей или можно их игнорировать?

```
struct {
  signed   X :1;
  unsigned Y :1;
} p;
```

Будут ли в структуре выше различия между X и Y?

Comment: Насколько помню, реализация битовых полей зависит от компилятора .-. И вообще, лучше их и не использовать - они весьма не ня переносимы.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>

struct C {
  signed   X :1;
  unsigned Y :1;
};

int main() {
    C c = {0};
    ++c.X;
    std::cout << c.X << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Похоже влияет, т.к. программа выводит -1 (компилятор gcc).
В принципе это логично, ибо однобитное знаковое число в дополнительном коде
может иметь только 2 значения - 0 и -1.

Answer (score 2):

@Алексей Сонькин, Вы правы, g++ под Linux пофигу на биты, точнее не совсем.
Если пытаться взять `sizeof(p.X);` то компилятор догадывается о том, что поле битовое, но при этом:

```
struct P {
    signed   X :1;
    unsigned Y :1;
};

int main(void) {

    P p = {0};

    (--p.X)--;
    (--p.Y)--;

    std::cout << "Y: " << p.Y << "; X:" << p.X << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Дает в ответе: `Y: 4294967294; X:-2`.

А вот этот вариант:

```
(++p.X)++;
(++p.Y)++;
```

Дает: Y: 2; X:2

Может я чего-то не понимаю?

Comment: Хех, в VS10 оба варианта, как и ожидал я, дали 0... И sizeof он, как и адрес, применять не разрешает =)

Видимо, g++ с полями как-то не особо дружит .з.

Comment: Алексей Сонькин, "И sizeof он, как и адрес, применять не разрешает =)"

Что вы имеете ввиду? Мой компилятор сказал, что нельзя применять к битовым полям. "invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to a bit-field"

Comment: Вот-вот, примерно тоже он и говорит=) Нельзя применять подобные операции к битовым полям (что вполне логично). В отладочной версии он этот несчастный инкремент поля растянул на двадцать команд ^^"

Comment: Да это понятно, просто для интересу сделал. Ибо на С++ не программирую уже давно. А для общего развития тема интересная.

@Фыва, а почему бы вам не использовать тип short и извлекать из него необходимые биты?

Comment: Странно, на моем gcc (4.5.2) нули в обоих случаях выдает.

Answer (score 0):

Перенесёмся в великие времена, когда программисты не знали про дот неты и джавы и программировали исключительно на ассемблерах. Вот тогда всё и зародилось и двоичная арифметика стала править миром.
Вообщем для ясности скажу:
Число помеченое signed задействует старший бит на знак в итоге само число записывается в оставшиеся биты. а Unsigned использует все биты под число. Вот и вся разница.
Надеюсь рассказывать не нужно, как принято работать  с signed числами и как представляются в двоичной арифметики отрицательные числа.

Comment: Вообще-то он спрашивал про влияние знака на битовые поля, размер коих один бит.

Comment: Тогда, раз он так спрашивал, если знаку нужен один бит, то тогда и влияние будет прямым. signed   X :1; при установки бита в 1 X будет равнятся -1 а в 0 X = нулю в unsigned Y :1; при установки бита в 1 это и будет y= 1 а в 0 тоже будет y= 0.
Собственно принято обозначать всё, как unsigned x: <колличество_битов> ну а для случая когда 1 бит я объяснил.